# How do I check the answer, and move to the next slot only if the first answer is correct? How to only track 1 boolean, and how to reset bool states?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, if-statement

I'm fairly new to Unity and I'm trying to make a punnett square game (Biology concept). Below is an image of the UI:

[image: Punnett Square UI]

There are 4 slots and they're supposed to be answered in order from slot1 (top left), slot 2(top right), slot 3 (bottom left), and slot 4 (bottom right). I'd like to ask your help in writing an efficient code for it so that they could be answered in order. I would also appreciate your help with 2 other problems: How do I track only the answer in slot1 when slot1 is the one being answered, and have the other booleans be unaffected? Lastly, how do I reset the state of the whole punnett square and have the booleans set to false, and slot1 to be the slotToAnswer again?

Here is the line of code I've tried to use

```
using Mono.Cecil.Cil;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using TMPro;
using Unity.Jobs;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;
using UnityEngine.SocialPlatforms;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class AnswerScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public bool isCorrect1, isCorrect2, isCorrect3, isCorrect4, allCorrect;
    public QuizManager quizManager;
    public GameObject slotToAnswer;
    public string firstAnswer, secondAnswer, thirdAnswer, fourthAnswer, answer;
    public TextMeshProUGUI dominantText, heteroText, recessiveText;
    public Button dominantButton, heteroButton, recessiveButton;

    public void Start()
    {
        // Initializing the buttons
        dominantButton = GameObject.Find("Dominant").GetComponent<Button>();
        heteroButton = GameObject.Find("Heterozygous").GetComponent<Button>();
        recessiveButton = GameObject.Find("Recessive").GetComponent<Button>();

        // Initializing the text
        dominantText = dominantButton.GetComponentInChildren<TextMeshProUGUI>();
        heteroText = heteroButton.GetComponentInChildren<TextMeshProUGUI>();
        recessiveText = recessiveButton.GetComponentInChildren<TextMeshProUGUI>();

        // Initializing the first slot to answer
        slotToAnswer = GameObject.Find("Slot1");

        isCorrect1 = false;
        isCorrect2 = false;
        isCorrect3 = false;
        isCorrect4 = false;
        allCorrect = false;

    }
    public void Update()
    {

        firstAnswer = quizManager.allele1.text + quizManager.allele3.text;
        if (firstAnswer == "aA")
        {
            firstAnswer = "Aa";
        }
        secondAnswer = quizManager.allele2.text + quizManager.allele3.text;
        if (secondAnswer == "aA")
        {
            secondAnswer = "Aa";
        }
        thirdAnswer = quizManager.allele1.text + quizManager.allele4.text;
        if (thirdAnswer == "aA")
        {
            thirdAnswer = "Aa";
        }
        fourthAnswer = quizManager.allele2.text + quizManager.allele4.text;
        if (fourthAnswer == "aA")
        {
            fourthAnswer = "Aa";
        }

        dominantButton.onClick.AddListener(TexttoDominant);
        heteroButton.onClick.AddListener(TexttoHetero);
        recessiveButton.onClick.AddListener(TexttoRecessive);
        answer = slotToAnswer.GetComponentInChildren<TextMeshProUGUI>().text;

        if (answer == firstAnswer)
        {
            isCorrect1 = true;
            slotToAnswer = GameObject.Find("Slot2");
            answer = slotToAnswer.GetComponentInChildren<TextMeshProUGUI>().text;
        }
        if (answer == secondAnswer)
        {
            isCorrect2 = true;
            slotToAnswer = GameObject.Find("Slot3");
            answer = slotToAnswer.GetComponentInChildren<TextMeshProUGUI>().text;
        } if (answer == thirdAnswer){
            isCorrect3 = true;
            slotToAnswer = GameObject.Find("Slot4");
            answer = slotToAnswer.GetComponentInChildren<TextMeshProUGUI>().text;
        } if (answer == fourthAnswer)
        {
            isCorrect4 = true;
            Debug.Log("Congrats!");
            allCorrect = true;
        }
  }
    // Button methods
    public void TexttoDominant()
    {
        slotToAnswer.GetComponentInChildren<TextMeshProUGUI>().text = dominantText.text;
    }
    public void TexttoHetero()
    {
        slotToAnswer.GetComponentInChildren<TextMeshProUGUI>().text = heteroText.text;
    }
    public void TexttoRecessive()
    {
        slotToAnswer.GetComponentInChildren<TextMeshProUGUI>().text = recessiveText.text;
    }
}
```

In the image, the correct answer for slot1 would be "Aa". As said in the title, I would like to make it so that slotToAnswer will be slot1 until the text inside slot1 is equal to Aa. Once slot1 text is equal to Aa, I would like to have the next slot (slot2) to be the slotToAnswer, and the process to continue until slot4. As of now, it only works when I input only the correct answers and in correct order. When I input the supposed answer for slot2 in slot1 on purpose, the boolean isCorrect2 for slot2 is set to true and the slotToAnswer becomes Slot3 (bottom left square) and everything goes into shambles. I would like to only affect the boolean related to a slot and not the other booleans. Lastly, when they are allCorrect, I would like to reset all values and start again.

I'm sorry if my explanation is hard to understand as I am a beginner. I appreciate all the help you guys will be able to provide! <3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the simplest answer here is to check the `slotToAnswer` value AND the actual answer to make sure they align. Your checks above don't account for which scenario should be checked, so it checks every answer until it finds one that's right.

Take note of the `else if` instead of `if` so that it doesn't attempt to validate each answer regardless of the question.

```
    public void Update()
    {

        firstAnswer = quizManager.allele1.text + quizManager.allele3.text;
        if (firstAnswer == "aA")
        {
            firstAnswer = "Aa";
        }
        secondAnswer = quizManager.allele2.text + quizManager.allele3.text;
        if (secondAnswer == "aA")
        {
            secondAnswer = "Aa";
        }
        thirdAnswer = quizManager.allele1.text + quizManager.allele4.text;
        if (thirdAnswer == "aA")
        {
            thirdAnswer = "Aa";
        }
        fourthAnswer = quizManager.allele2.text + quizManager.allele4.text;
        if (fourthAnswer == "aA")
        {
            fourthAnswer = "Aa";
        }

        dominantButton.onClick.AddListener(TexttoDominant);
        heteroButton.onClick.AddListener(TexttoHetero);
        recessiveButton.onClick.AddListener(TexttoRecessive);
        answer = slotToAnswer.GetComponentInChildren<TextMeshProUGUI>().text;
// There are better ways to do this, but this is likely the easiest without restructuring your entire class.
        if (slotToAnswer == GameObject.Find("Slot1") && answer == firstAnswer)
        {
            isCorrect1 = true;
            slotToAnswer = GameObject.Find("Slot2");
            answer = slotToAnswer.GetComponentInChildren<TextMeshProUGUI>().text;
        }
        else if (slotToAnswer == GameObject.Find("Slot2") && answer == secondAnswer)
        {
            isCorrect2 = true;
            slotToAnswer = GameObject.Find("Slot3");
            answer = slotToAnswer.GetComponentInChildren<TextMeshProUGUI>().text;
        } 
        else if (slotToAnswer == GameObject.Find("Slot3") && answer == thirdAnswer){
            isCorrect3 = true;
            slotToAnswer = GameObject.Find("Slot4");
            answer = slotToAnswer.GetComponentInChildren<TextMeshProUGUI>().text;
        } 
        else if (slotToAnswer == GameObject.Find("Slot4") && answer == fourthAnswer)
        {
            isCorrect4 = true;
            Debug.Log("Congrats!");
            allCorrect = true;
        }
  }
    ... The rest here was the same
```

Comment: Thank you, this is what I was looking for! Out of curiosity, if I were to restructure that block of code, would the "better way" you mentioned be the use of for loops?

Comment: Honestly, without knowing more about Unity (I know almost nothing about it), and taking a deeper dive, when I say "better" it's really subjective. The best way is what makes the most sense to you and gets the job done.